# curve_fit with multiple variables

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to make a curve fit of measured data from a towing tank carriage. Since the carriage is moving during the test there are 2 input variables namely time t and location x.

Now python says popt has 5 results instead of my expected 4 results.

I came up with the following script:

```
import scipy.optimize

x = np.zeros( len(data_foil[str(rn)]['src1']['time']))
for j in range(1,len(data_foil[str(rn)]['src1']['time'])):
    x[j] = x[j-1] + data_rough[str(rn)]['src1']['Vm'][j]*0.001

yy = data_rough[str(rn)]['src1']['Whm1']
t = data_rough[str(rn)]['src1']['time']
t = np.array(t)
yy = np.array(yy)
ff = np.fft.fftfreq(len(t), (t[1]-t[0]))   # assume uniform spacing Fast Fourier Transformation
Fyy = abs(np.fft.rfft(yy))
guess_freq = abs(ff[np.argmax(Fyy[1:])+1])   # excluding the zero frequency "peak", which is related to offset
guess_amp = np.std(yy) * 2.**0.5
guess_offset = np.mean(yy)
guess = np.array([guess_amp, 2.*np.pi*guess_freq, 0.1, guess_offset])
g=9.81
def cosfunc(X, t, zeta_a, omega, p, c):
    g=9.81
    x,t = X
    return zeta_a * np.cos((omega**2/g)*x - omega*t + p) + c

popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(cosfunc, (x, t), yy, p0=guess)
zeta_a, k, omega, p, c = popt
```

Comment: Could you edit your example to simplify `data_foil` and `data_rough`, and provide some mock data? Perhaps a vector created with `np.random.rand` after `np.random.seed`.

Answer (score 0):

The function used in `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` "takes the independent variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as separate remaining arguments" (source: [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)).

Your function `cosfunc` has the independent variables as the first two arguments. So `curve_fit` assumes the second argument (`t`) is a parameter to be optimised, hence why it outputs 5 arguments.

Changing the `cosfunc` definition to take a tuple as the first argument should fix your issue. I think this is what you meant to do, as suggested by your line `x,t = X`.